# Removing part of a branch

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

In our codebase we are using the following structure, using TFS

```
/
  - Build
  - Development
    - Dev1
    - Dev2
  - Main
  - Releases
    - Rel1
    - Rel2
```

The Development and Releases sections contain branches off main. The Build section sits outside the branching.
Within each of the branches there is a section which should not have been included within the branching which I would like to move under Build.

Is it possible to move this section out and remove its branching information?

If I do a rename what impact might this have when creating new branches or merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get rid of the branching history, you'll need to go to the command line and do a TF Destroy.

Once you do that, you can rebranch to where it needs to go.